# free form wordpress

Tags: forms

My question is kind of simple: I have a voucher. I would like to people fill an form on my WordPress site and when they click submit, they receive an e-mail with the voucher...

Is there a plugin out there for that? If there is not, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

you can do that very simply with [contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin that lets you send two emails on every form submit, so on the first mail collect all of the form fields and send it to your self and in the 2nd email just mail the user the voucher.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks (I dont know how to write your name) hehe that solution help me a lot! I appreciate

Comment: Glad i Could help.